# bash pass ip address to a URL in my script

Tags: bash

http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=

I need some help to write a bash script that will allow me to pass any given IP to this URL. The site above is URL I'd like to my script to call. Can someone get me started? Thanks!

I'd like to use my script like this: echo IP_ADDRESS | geoiptool

When I echo an IP and pipe it to my script, I get this error below. Is that because
the pipe command is not installed?

-bash-3.2$ echo 173.192.108.135 | geo
-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a command line parameter instead of reading from stdin. You can use $1 to refer to the first parameter, $2 for the second, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$1
```

Then you just fire it by:

```
geoiptool <IP>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a benefit to doing it this way? vs doing a 'echo <IP> | geoiptool'

Comment: It will work just fine either way but this is the more traditional "unixish" way of doing it. Pipes are generally used for filters -- programs like sed or grep that take some large amount of input, do something to it, and then spit it back out. Command line arguments are generally used for indicating options and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read` command to read from `stdin` and store the address in a variable.  Then use `wget` to issue the HTTP request:

```
read ip
wget http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$ip
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay.

You can use the `read` command to read a line from `stdin` and assign it to a variable:

```
read variable
echo "You said: $variable"
```

And `curl` is a commonly installed command-line tool for interacting with HTTP URLs:

```
curl http://www.google.com/
```

(You can also use `wget` or `lynx` or another tool, depending on your requirements).

So a very simple script might look like:

```
URL="http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP="
read ipaddr
curl --silent "$URL$ipaddr"
```